# jquery form plugin double submission occur

Tags: jquery, forms, plugins

I have two containers on my page:

```
<div id="foto_1"><span>Change foto</span><img src="" /></div>
<div id="foto_2"><span>Change foto</span><img src="" /></div>
```

And form plugin .ajaxSubmit() wrapped in my own function:

```
function imgUpload(div_id) {

 $('#myimgForm').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).ajaxSubmit(
    {
        target:  '',
        success: function(data) {  

        var new_data = data.split('.');
        var path = new_data[0]+'_sm.'+new_data[1];
        $('#foto_'+div_id+' img').attr('src', '');
        $('#foto_'+div_id+' img').attr('src', path);

        },
        resetForm: true

    }); 
    return false;
  });
}
```

Then I call my function:

```
$('#foto_1 span').click(function(){

    imgUpload(1);
});

$('#foto_2 span').click(function(){

    imgUpload(2);
});
```

So the problem lies in the fact that when i click on the second container, .ajaxsubmit() performed twice. What's the reason? I tried unbind('live') before click, also simple bind() and simple click() - no change... Please help

Here is an html form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="myimgForm" name="myimgForm" action="/save_image_form.php"> 
    <div id="imgForm_div">
        <div id="img_input"><input type="file" name="caret" /></div>
        <input type="button" id="cancel_img" value="Cancel" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
$('#myimgForm').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).ajaxSubmit(
    {
```

Please note also that `live()` is deprecated.

Comment: I added html form into a question

Comment: I don't see why you're making this as a jquery ui function. Do you have a demo?

Comment: What's the difference ? Before this example my function was more simple : function imgUpload(div_id) {} . I can't show a demo because it's part of admin panel

Comment: I didn't ask you to simplify the function, I was just curious why this was made in that way. It looks like you need to create some demo or fiddle, it's hard to say why it works so without full source of the files.

Comment: I found the reason ) When you click second container .ajaxSubmit() execute twice because submit button click in form also call this function. So I ruled out .ajaxSubmit() from my own function. It must be at once, independent. And thank you AlecTMH for preventDefault )